# Pass Complex Object to Controller in MVC using Ajax

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to pass an array of complex objects to the controller via ajax. Using the network debugger, I can see that the data is being passed to the controller, however, the parameter ise not being populated properly.

My Javascript is as follows:

```
function objectifyForm(formArray) {

    var returnArray = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
        returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
    }
    return returnArray;
}

function ContractPost() {

    var businessInfoForm = objectifyForm($("#form-business-info").serializeArray());
    var gsvForm = objectifyForm($("#form-contract-gsv").serializeArray());



 var BusinessInfo = JSON.stringify(businessInfoForm);
        var StreetViewContract = JSON.stringify(gsvForm);

        var vmData = [{
            BusinessInfo,
            StreetViewContract
        }];


        var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ 'viewModel':vmData[0] });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Bundle/ContractPost")", 
            data: dataToSend,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //businessInfo.html(data);
                alert(data.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
```

My controller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContractPost(ContractBundleModel viewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

The data being passed from the network is as follows:

[image]

As you can see the viewModel object in the parameter is not being populated properly:

[image]

My request payload is as follows:

```
{"viewModel":{"BusinessInfo":"{\"business_name\":\"Megan's Test Text\",\"address1\":\"915 E Lincoln Hwy\",\"address2\":\"\",\"city\":\"Jacksonville Beach\",\"state\":\"FL\",\"zip\":\"32250\",\"email\":\"megan.moser@ampcorporate.com\",\"website\":\"\",\"contact\":\"Megan Moser\",\"phone1\":\"8157876355\",\"mobile\":\"\",\"business_category\":\"\",\"AptDate\":\"\",\"AptTime\":\"\",\"appointment_tbd\":\"false\"}","StreetViewContract":"{\"business_name\":\"\",\"address1\":\"\",\"address2\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"AL\",\"zip\":\"\",\"email\":\"\",\"website\":\"\",\"contact\":\"\",\"phone1\":\"\",\"mobile\":\"\",\"business_category\":\"\",\"AptDate\":\"\",\"AptTime\":\"\",\"appointment_tbd\":\"false\",\"program_id\":\"4\",\"fee\":\"0\",\"discount\":\"0\",\"tax_exempt\":\"false\",\"sales_tax\":\"0\",\"grand_total\":\"0\",\"contract_number\":\"\",\"customer_number\":\"\",\"rep.empid\":\"\"}"}}
```

My ViewModel is as follows:

```
public class ContractBundleModel
{
        public contract BusinessInfo { get; set; }
        public contract PrintContract { get; set; }
        public contract OptimaContract { get; set; }
        public contract StreetViewContract { get; set; }
        public contract TextContract { get; set; }

}
```

...and a contract (generated from EntityFramework) object is as follows:

```
public class contract
    {
        public contract();

        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string address_alt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? appointment_date { get; set; }
        public bool appointment_tbd { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string business_category { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string business_category2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string business_category3 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string business_category4 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string business_category5 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string business_category6 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string business_category7 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string business_category8 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string business_name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string city { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string city_alt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? completed { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string contact { get; set; }
        public int? contract_number { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string created_by { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string created_note { get; set; }
        public int? customer_number { get; set; }
        public DateTime? deleted { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string deleted_by { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string deleted_note { get; set; }
        public double discount { get; set; }
        public bool discount_print_opt { get; set; }
        public int? doc_id { get; set; }
        public int doc_set_id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string existing_customer_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string fax { get; set; }
        public double fee { get; set; }
        public double grand_total { get; set; }
        public double gsv_delivery_fee { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string gsv_delivery_option { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool inside_sale { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string lead { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string mobile { get; set; }
        public DateTime? modified { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string modified_by { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string modified_note { get; set; }
        public DateTime? notification_sent { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string phone1 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string phone2 { get; set; }
        public bool previous_contract { get; set; }
        public int? previous_contract_number { get; set; }
        public bool print_attachment_camera_ready { get; set; }
        public bool print_attachment_email { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_attachment_opt { get; set; }
        public double print_bcat_price1 { get; set; }
        public double print_bcat_price2 { get; set; }
        public double print_bcat_price_each1 { get; set; }
        public double print_bcat_price_each2 { get; set; }
        public int print_bcat_quantity1 { get; set; }
        public int print_bcat_quantity2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_builder_ad_size_opt { get; set; }
        public double print_builder_price1 { get; set; }
        public double print_builder_price2 { get; set; }
        public double print_builder_price_each1 { get; set; }
        public double print_builder_price_each2 { get; set; }
        public int print_builder_quantity1 { get; set; }
        public int print_builder_quantity2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_builder_special_offer1 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_builder_special_offer2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_builder_special_offer_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_bw_page1_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_bw_page2_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_bw_page3_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_bw_page4_opt { get; set; }
        public double print_bw_price { get; set; }
        public bool print_bw_section_sponsor { get; set; }
        public bool print_bw_special_placement { get; set; }
        public bool print_bw_wp_sponsor { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_cat_opt { get; set; }
        public double print_cat_price { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_color_banner_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_color_bic_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_color_boc_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_color_fic_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_color_foc_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_color_insert_opt { get; set; }
        public double print_color_price { get; set; }
        public bool print_color_special_placement { get; set; }
        public bool print_color_spine { get; set; }
        public string print_directories { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_display_ad_type_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_expedite_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string print_listing1 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string print_listing2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_renewal_opt { get; set; }
        public double print_terms_full_fee { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string print_wp_emphasis_opt { get; set; }
        public int product_id { get; set; }
        public int program_id { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public rep rep { get; set; }
        public int rep_id { get; set; }
        public double sales_tax { get; set; }
        public double sales_tax_rate { get; set; }
        public int save_version { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string state { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string state_alt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? submitted { get; set; }
        public bool subscription_mode { get; set; }
        public double subscription_monthly_fee { get; set; }
        public double subscription_setup_fee { get; set; }
        public bool tax_exempt { get; set; }
        public double txt_add_location_fee { get; set; }
        public bool txt_add_location_opt { get; set; }
        public int txt_add_location_quantity { get; set; }
        public bool txt_add_vanity_code { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string txt_materials_opt { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string txt_vanity_code { get; set; }
        public DateTime? validated { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string vanity { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string website { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string zip { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string zip_alt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting [FromBody] in your receiving controller?

Comment: I have not tried that approach yet.  Does the receiving controller, then, need to accept a [FromBody] ContractBundleModel viewModel OR [FromBody] string viewModel?

Comment: I decided to split the view model to individual objects and send as parameters. The parameter objects are now populating .